# How to bind to element inside contentcontrol in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm relativly new to WPF and currently working on a prototype. In this project i use contentcontrols and custom usercontrols quite a bit.

The structure is basically:
MainWindow -> Ribbon + TabControl of MainViews

MainView -> ContentView + EditPanel

EditPanel -> DetailInfo + Editor

Now this editor contains a FrameworkElement that exposes some commands that i want to bind to from the ribbon,but i can't get the binding to work. MainView and EditPanel are usercontrols.

The MainWindow Xaml looks basically like this:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Command="{Binding ElementName="MainTabControl", Path=SelectedContent.xxxx      }" />

> this gives me the MainViewModel, not the MainView


        <Ribbon Grid.Row="0" />
        <TabControl Name="MainTabControl"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMainViewModels}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <view:MainView DataContext="{Binding Data}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

MainView.xaml can be boiled down to:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            ...
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ContentControl Grid.Column="0"
                        Content="{Binding CurrentContentView}" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <View:QuickEditView DataContext="{Binding CurrentViewViewModel.SelectedItem}" />
            </ContentControl.Content>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

and finally the QuickEditView that has an editor element that exposes the needed commands:

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <sccontrols:MemoEditControl />
    ...
</Grid>
```

There is no problem if i try a binding from the MainView to the editorcontrol, but i can't get it to work from the Ribbon in the MainWindow. 
The problem seems to me that i can't get at the MainView in the tabcontrol. the selecteditem as well as the selectedcontent is a MainViewModel, not a MainView and i'm reluctant to keep a reference to the view in the viewmodel

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

edit: MainViewModel in broad strokes

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyChanged etc
{
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DisplayStyles> AvailableDisplayStyles {...}
public DisplayStyles SelectedDisplayStyle {...}

public SelectableListViewModelBase<DetailViewModel> CurrentViewViewModel{...}
public System.Windows.Controls.Control CurrentContentView{...}

...
}
```

the MainWindowViewModel holds not much but a list of MainViewModels as well as the selectedMainviewModel + bunch of commands

my current ideas are either to run through the visual tree to find the right element (i suspect the performance will be an issue here), or to push the element up through dependency properties on the encapsulating controls(bit of a nightmare to maintain in the long run i imagine)

Comment: Can you also post the class definitions for your data contexts?

Comment: as theres a lot of company stuff in there i can only post a broad outline

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't see any details about the ribbon in your posted code... so basically, the problematic part is not in the question?

Comment: the ribbon is not actually the problem, even binding from a simple button doesn't work

Comment: @ChristianKoch typically when this sort of thing happens it's best to first try replicating the scenario in a test application, without involving company code or mocking it in generic terms. That way we can help identify the problem without exposing your company code.

Comment: _"theres a lot of company stuff in there i can only post a broad outline"_ -- posting a "broad outline" is what makes your question too broad, and it should be closed as such. What you _can_ do is rewrite your question so that it uses a _simple_ [mcve] that shows clearly _only the pieces of the problem that are relevant_.